# Solver function in excel referencing VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, solver

I am trying to minimize using the Solver tool, in Excel 2010,

```
ABS(expectedPayout(H3,H6,H5,H7,H8,H4)-H21)
```

where expectedPayout is a function I created in VBA. The solver will run, but it is giving me a nonsense answer. Since expectedPayout is a created function, can solver not really work with this?

Thanks

EDIT: adding more info

My data is in the form of a+bi, where a and b are constants that can be manipulated, and i are doubles.

My goal is to try to optimize a and b, such that the difference between expectedPayout, and H21, is a as close to zero as possible

Here is the code for expectedPayout

```
Function expectedPayout(age As Double, payment As Double, rate As Double, coL As Double,  guaranteedTime As Integer, gender As String)

Dim discountFactor As Double
Dim expectedValue As Double
Dim prob As Double

discountFactor = 1 / (1 + rate)
expectedValue = 0


For i = (age + guaranteedTime + 1) To 115       'stochastic payments
        prob = 1
        For Each cell In Range("B" & age + 3 & ":B" & i + 3)
            prob = prob * (1 - cell.Value)
        Next
        expectedValue = expectedValue + payment * ((1 + coL) ^ (i - (age + 1))) * prob * (discountFactor ^ (i - age))
Next

For i = 1 To guaranteedTime                         'deterministic payments
    expectedValue = expectedValue + payment * ((1 + coL) ^ (i - 1)) * (discountFactor ^ i)
Next

expectedPayout = expectedValue

End Function
```

Comment: We need much more detail.........your formulas........your **UDF** ........your data, etc.

Comment: When you're saying "solver", do you mean 1) the `ABS()` function? 2) the "thing" that populates your `H` column? or 3) the `expectedPayout()` function?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, I added some edits that should make things clearer - sorry about that.

Comment: @CST-Link, I mean the solver tool in Excel used for optimization

Comment: @GordonUnderwood Oops, didn't know such an add-in existed. Sorry for the dumb question, and thanks for showing me something new.

Comment: @GordonUnderwood I would calculate the function in the spreadsheet instead, so that the solver can work. It seems that you need `SUMPRODUCT`s and additions only, so it definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solver does not really work with user-defined functions. I recommend that you rather create a new function that is the inverse of whatever `expectedPayout` calculates and use that instead of Solver.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean writing my own optimization algorithm in VBA? Seems very complicated.